# Spark 3.1.1 | Unable to run job : IDENTIFIER expected instead of '['

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I'm trying to run a code that runs in spark 2.4.4 and I'm having the following error:

```
21/08/20 08:35:05 ERROR CodeGenerator: failed to compile: org.codehaus.commons.compiler.CompileException: File 'generated.java', Line 75, Column 32: IDENTIFIER expected instead of '['
org.codehaus.commons.compiler.CompileException: File 'generated.java', Line 75, Column 32: IDENTIFIER expected instead of '['
    at org.codehaus.janino.TokenStreamImpl.read(TokenStreamImpl.java:196)
    at org.codehaus.janino.Parser.read(Parser.java:3705)
    at org.codehaus.janino.Parser.parseQualifiedIdentifier(Parser.java:446)
    at org.codehaus.janino.Parser.parseReferenceType(Parser.java:2569)
    at org.codehaus.janino.Parser.parseType(Parser.java:2549)
    at org.codehaus.janino.Parser.parseFormalParameter(Parser.java:1688)
    at org.codehaus.janino.Parser.parseFormalParameterList(Parser.java:1639)
    at org.codehaus.janino.Parser.parseFormalParameters(Parser.java:1620)
    at org.codehaus.janino.Parser.parseMethodDeclarationRest(Parser.java:1518)
    at org.codehaus.janino.Parser.parseClassBodyDeclaration(Parser.java:1028)
    at org.codehaus.janino.Parser.parseClassBody(Parser.java:841)
    at org.codehaus.janino.Parser.parseClassDeclarationRest(Parser.java:736)
    at org.codehaus.janino.Parser.parseClassBodyDeclaration(Parser.java:941)
    at org.codehaus.janino.ClassBodyEvaluator.cook(ClassBodyEvaluator.java:234)
    at org.codehaus.janino.SimpleCompiler.cook(SimpleCompiler.java:205)
    at org.codehaus.commons.compiler.Cookable.cook(Cookable.java:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.CodeGenerator$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$expressions$codegen$CodeGenerator$$doCompile(CodeGenerator.scala:1427)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.CodeGenerator$$anon$1.load(CodeGenerator.scala:1524)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.CodeGenerator$$anon$1.load(CodeGenerator.scala:1521)
    at org.sparkproject.guava.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3599)
    at org.sparkproject.guava.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2379)
    at org.sparkproject.guava.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2342)
    at org.sparkproject.guava.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2257)
    at org.sparkproject.guava.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:4000)
    at org.sparkproject.guava.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:4004)
    at org.sparkproject.guava.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4874)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.CodeGenerator$.compile(CodeGenerator.scala:1375)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.liftedTree1$1(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:721)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.doExecute(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:720)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$execute$1(SparkPlan.scala:185)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:223)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:220)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:134)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:133)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.sources.ForeachBatchSink.addBatch(ForeachBatchSink.scala:33)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runBatch$16(MicroBatchExecution.scala:586)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker$.withTracker(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withTracker(SQLExecution.scala:232)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.executeQuery$1(SQLExecution.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$6(SQLExecution.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker$.withTracker(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withTracker(SQLExecution.scala:232)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:253)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:134)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:772)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runBatch$15(MicroBatchExecution.scala:584)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:357)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken$(ProgressReporter.scala:355)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runBatch(MicroBatchExecution.scala:584)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runActivatedStream$2(MicroBatchExecution.scala:226)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:357)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken$(ProgressReporter.scala:355)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1(MicroBatchExecution.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.OneTimeExecutor.execute(TriggerExecutor.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runActivatedStream(MicroBatchExecution.scala:188)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:333)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:244)
```

I read something in the official documentation regarding the way that spark 3.1.1 handles the maps, arrays, etc:

> In Spark 3.1, structs and maps are wrapped by the {} brackets in
> casting them to strings. For instance, the show() action and the CAST
> expression use such brackets. In Spark 3.0 and earlier, the []
> brackets are used for the same purpose. To restore the behavior before
> Spark 3.1, you can set
> spark.sql.legacy.castComplexTypesToString.enabled to true.
>
> In Spark 3.1, NULL elements of structures, arrays and maps are
> converted to “null” in casting them to strings. In Spark 3.0 or
> earlier, NULL elements are converted to empty strings. To restore the
> behavior before Spark 3.1, you can set
> spark.sql.legacy.castComplexTypesToString.enabled to true.

I have enabled this, but still no luck. I'm removing all the maps and arrays from my dataframe meanwhile.

Any idea?

Comment: Whenever you face errors like yours it's likely a Spark bug to be reported in https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/SPARK. Can you show the streaming query? By `ForeachBatchSink.addBatch` I suspect the issue is before you execute the foreach code (so of less importance).